# SQL Each row consecutive date available

Tags: sql-server

How to create a query with SQL to get each row consecutive day room available. For example, i would like to find 3 days consecutive day with at least 3 available rooms

Original table

```
Date       Available rooms 
----       ---------------
01/12/16         4
02/12/16         5
03/12/16         5
04/12/16         5
05/12/16         4
06/12/16         0
07/12/16         3
08/12/16         4
09/12/16         4
```

with result below

```
Date      EndDate       
--------  --------
01/12/16  03/12/16
02/12/16  04/12/16
03/12/16  05/12/16
07/12/16  09/12/16
```

Comment: Your requirements are not clear at all.  Why don't you have entries in the desired result for 4th to 6th December in the `Date` column?

Comment: @TJB updated with the requirement. 3 days consecutive with at least 3 stocks available

Comment: Still not clear what is your requirement, please explain further, not everyone work with stocks.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza changed example with rooms

Comment: what happens if there are only two consecutive days?

Comment: @mcNets go to next date until it meets 3 consecutive days

Comment: for example: `05/12/16 = 0'

Comment: Can you explain first row of resultset `01/12/16  03/12/16`..why this result

Comment: @mcNets as the result table shown. it skipped the date and move to 07/12/16 and check if this date with 3 consecutive day with available room. IF 07/12/16 = 0 , the result only shows until 03/12/16 - 05/12/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/GSVX23058)**

```
SELECT T1.[Date], T3.[Date]
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table1 T2
  ON T1.[Date] = DATEADD(day, -1, T2.[Date])
JOIN Table1 T3
  ON T1.[Date] = DATEADD(day, -2, T3.[Date])
WHERE T1.[Available rooms] >= 3
  AND T2.[Available rooms] >= 3
  AND T3.[Available rooms] >= 3
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: If you have SQL 2012+ @Viki888 answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

Try using LEAD() function like below query

```
SELECT d as StartDate, EndDate
FROM
    (SELECT d, 
        CASE 
            WHEN available_rooms > 2 
                AND LEAD(available_rooms,1) OVER(order by d) > 2 
                AND LEAD(available_rooms,2) OVER(order by d) > 2 
            THEN LEAD(d,2) OVER(order by d) 
        END EndDate
    FROM table1 t) t1
WHERE EndDate is not null;
```

Below is the output I received

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer assuming a recent enough version of SQL Server.